# Persisting Spring stateMachine in Database

Tags: spring, persistence, spring-statemachine

I understand that this question might be repeated but seems like previous answers are not adequate to provide clarity.

I want to save statemachine into database and rebuild statemachine using previously persisted stage.

My application is  in Sprinng boot with JPA.

If I get any sample example that would be great.

Comment: And what exactly do you want to persist?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I want to persist state / StateMachineContext  of Statemachine. Example: Spring Statemachine which has all stages and events configured and initiated needs to be stored in DB so next time when I want to send / trigger an Event I don't have to create new Instance of Spring machine ( Cant have new machine every time ). This is what I have in mind but I want to persist in Relational Database (SQL) not in Memory. Please refer point 27.1 & 2. [link] (https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/html/sm-persist.html#sm-persist-statemachinecontext)

Answer (score -1):

There is a JpaStateMachineRuntimePersister that you can use.

Scroll all the way down to the bottom of the reference doc and you will find the link to:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/

Comment: Can you help me to understand how can I use **Class JpaRepositoryStateMachine** in simple implementation so that I can use it's method to get machine context in byte[] and store. Rebuilding from it is also required.

Comment: your link is down

Comment: Link fixed. Spring changed the URLs